# how to convert while loop into for loop

Tags: java, string, algorithm, matching

I'm working on string matching algorithms using java, I need to convert the while loop into for loop so easily deal with it.

the while loop in KMPSearch I need to convert into for loop
the purpose is to check for some characters to be skipped before the search process started. 
I don't know where to insert this portion of code

```
void KMPSearch(String txt, String pat) {

        int N=txt.length();
        int M=pat.length();
        int lps[]=new int[M];
        int j=0;// index of patt
        int i=0; //index of txt
        int c=0;
        computeLPS(lps,M,pat);
        //char [] skipChar=new char[] {'s','d','a','c'};

        while(i<N) {

            if(pat.charAt(j)==txt.charAt(i)) {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            if(j==M) {
                System.out.println("pattern found at index  "+ (i-j-c));
                j=lps[j-1];

            }
            else if (i<N && pat.charAt(j) != txt.charAt(i)) {


                if (j != 0) {
                    j=lps[j-1];
                }
                else {
                    i=i+1;
                }

            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: that change is much simpler than the code you've already written.

Comment: "I need to convert the while loop into for loop" Why? I do not get the explanation "so easily deal with it" or "the purpose is to check for some characters to be skipped before the search process started". The `for` loop will not magically do that. Are we looking at a XY problem? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Replace `while(i<N)` by `for(;i<N;)`. Does this really solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a loop that performs one iteration per character in `txt`. Your loop can be rewritten like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        char ch = txt.charAt(i);
        /* Perform your potential char test here */
        while (j > 0 && (j == M || pat.charAt(j) != ch)) {
            if (j == M) {
                System.out.println("pattern found at index  "+ (i-j-c));
            }
            j = lps[j-1];
        }
        if (pat.charAt(j) == ch) {
            j++;
        }
    }
```

It is not *exactly* the same, as in theory your loop could iterate with `j == M` at the start of the new iteration -- which would lead to an error. The above alternative will continue the inner while loop when that happens. But probably your `lps` is such that also your code will never run into that situation. So they are practically equivalent.